# html response in java + jsoup

Tags: java, html

I am working in Java and using JSoup to get the response of webpage.

While I am printing doc in html file, I am not able to get the page as it is. reason is it looks the css and js in wrong path.

Here the piece of response,

```
    <link href="../Style/STYLE.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="../Style/NKN.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="../Style/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="../Script/Validation.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="../Script/grid.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="../Script/api.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

While I am looking this in webpage view source and click on css, it goes to other url as follows,

```
    <link href="http://www.url.com/Style/STYLE.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://www.url.com/Style/NKN.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://www.url.com/Style/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="http://www.url.com/Script/Validation.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="http://www.url.com/Script/grid.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="http://www.url.com/Script/api.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I found a way to get absolute urls using Jsoup using Elements as follows,

```
    Elements links = document.select("link[href]");
    for (Element link : links) {
      system.out.println(link.attr("abs:href"));
    }
```

But it is useful for only iterating and printing the links, How may I replace in response doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution in a following way,

I am getting regex values for href and src in every string values, if it exists then I am creating new URLs and replace this new URL with them.

```
    Pattern patternHref = Pattern.compile(" href=\"(.*?)\"", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Pattern patternSrc = Pattern.compile("src=\"(.*?)\"", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

    Matcher matcher = patternSrc.matcher(eachResponseString);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        URL aa = new URL(url2, (matcher.group(1)));
        eachResponseString = patternUrl.matcher(eachResponseString).replaceAll(
                "(" + aa + ")");
        writer.write(eachResponseString);

    Matcher matcher1 = patternHref.matcher(eachResponseString);
    if (matcher1.find()) {
        URL aa = new URL(url2, (matcher.group(1)));
        eachResponseString = patternUrl.matcher1(eachResponseString).replaceAll(
                "(" + aa + ")");
        writer.write(eachResponseString);
```

This way everything works fine.

Hope this helps for others too.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [replaceAll()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method to replace all *href="..* to the links

```
    String response = getResponse(); //assuming that gerResponse is your function returning response of webpage
    String withLinks = response.replaceAll("href=\"..", "href=\"http://www.url.com");
```

You can also do it for **src** etc

---

EDIT: If you need to remove last part of URL (the script name with parameters)  you can get a substring from beginning to the last "**/**" sign

```
    response = response.subString(0, response.lastIndexOf("/"))
```

and then replaceAll urls

Comment: @antkowicz,  I tried that. But my URL is http://www.nakkheeran.in/Users/frmMagazine.aspx?M=2, when I am clicking links, it goes to http://www.nakkheeran.in/Users/newURL. But in response it shows as <a href='newURL'> if I make url string replace, it becomes <a href = 'http://www.nakkheeran.in/Users/frmMagazine.aspx?M=2/newURL'. I also tried to get host name and add it, but here, host is  www.nakkheeran.in. I need www.nakkheeran.in/Users for this links.